# Split string by word contain space in Java

Tags: regex, string, java-8

I have a String pattern: **"hh:mm:ss dd:MM:yyyy to hh:mm:ss dd:MM:yyyy"** and I want to extract date String from it.

Example:

**S = "00:00:00 19/08/2022 to 23:59:59 19/08/2022"**

Split into **S1 = "00:00:00 19/08/2022"** and **S2 = "23:59:59 19/08/2022"**.

I'm trying to use String.split function but can't figure out the regex yet. Can somebody help?

I'm using Java 8.

Comment: This Question should be re-opened. It has focus: *How to extract a date from such a string*. I have another Answer prepared to post, in addition to the already existing correct and interesting [Answer by Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73713368/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you for your comment sir! How do you think i should edit the question so it can be re-open?

Comment: We just need one more vote to re-open. I don’t have any editing suggestions for you, seems good enough as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split on `\s+to\s+`:

```java
String pattern = "00:00:00 19/08/2022 to 23:59:59 19/08/2022";
String[] parts = pattern.split("\\s+to\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[00:00:00 19/08/2022, 23:59:59 19/08/2022]
```